# GCP GKE - Loadbalancer alternative

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

I'm using lb for prod site. But for internal services (like gitlab, jenkins) I don't want to host a lb. Is there any alternative way to connect to internal services without the use of load balancers? Like could any bastion host do the job?

Having lb for prod and internal services seems to cost around 35 to 45 dollars.  I'm trying to reduce the total bill.

I have a nginx ingress controller for production site, wondering if I could do something with it using  subdomains for internal services.

Comment: Could you specify what you exactly mean by "internal services" ? Are those microservices deployed on the same gke cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Services on a Kubernetes cluster can talk to each other using their ClusterIP, without any use of a load balancer. The IP can be returned using the internal DNS service such as KubeDNS or CoreDNS

[For more details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

If you need to connect services in different clusters i’d take a look at Kubefed or Submarier for Multi-Cluster deployment.
Which by the way also harness the use of DNS service discovery (this is the term used for in-kubernetes service communication) for service-to-service communication.
[Kubefed](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed)
[Submariner](https://submariner.io/)